# pandas - Summing over rows with strings collapses my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to match information in rows for different group and thought a summation would work well.

example code:

```
data = [{'measure':'pressure','name':'A','t1':'off','t2':'on'},
        {'measure':'pressure','name':'B','t1':'on','t2':'off'},
        {'measure':'pressure','name':'C','t1':'off','t2':'on'}, 
        {'measure':'power','name':'A','t1':'off','t2':'on'}, 
        {'measure':'power','name':'B','t1':'on','t2':'nan'},
        {'measure':'power','name':'C','t1':'off','t2':'on'}
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.set_index(['measure','name'])
```

looks like:

```
                t1   t2
measure  name          
pressure A     off   on
         B      on  off
         C     off   on
power    A     off   on
         B      on  nan
         C     off   on
```

I'd like to have reported which `name` has a corresponding value for two different index groups, by adding a new row to the DF, as shown below:

```
                t1   t2
measure  name          
pressure A     off   on
         B      on  off
         C     off   on
power    A     off   on
         B      on  nan
         C     off   on
On       sum     B  A,C
```

(i.e. store which `name`s have both `power` and `pressure` equal "on")

`df2 = df.loc[['measure']].groupby(['name']).sum())`

and then work with `df2`
However, my df2 has only 1 column instead of the original n.
I'd like to get something like:

```
          t1     t2
name          
A     offoff   onon
B       onon    off
C     offoff   onon
```

and then apply further masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nan`s are missing values or strings is possible first replace it by empty strings and then use `join`:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).fillna('').groupby('name').agg(''.join)
print (df)
          t1    t2
name              
A     offoff  onon
B       onon   off
C     offoff  onon
```

Or using `sum`:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).fillna('').sum(level='name')
```

working same like:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).fillna('').groupby('name').sum()
```

Comment: I think adding `.fillna('')` did it for me. This works, thanks

Comment: Perhaps a word of advice on how to go from the thusly created `df` to collecting information on which `name` groups have "onon" value? I was thinking of something like:  `df.mask(df =="onon", df.index[n], inplace=True)` where n is the integer count value of with the row. Is that simple or complex?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
res = df.groupby(['name']).agg(lambda x: ''.join(s for s in x if s != 'nan'))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          t1    t2
name              
A     offoff  onon
B       onon   off
C     offoff  onon
```

Comment: whoops, missed that `nan` my bad!